# How to properly combine and export (as raster) vector lines on top of raster

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a georeferenced TIFF with building plans on it. I then laid topo lines on top of it. it looks right in QGis. I now want to export this as an image (i.e. with the topo lines overlaid). How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: current solution is loading geotiff into google earth, then loading in vector lines, then exporting a cropped screenshot....

Comment: Can you use Print Composer and then print to PDF with something like PDFCreater? The PDF would not be georeferenced.

Comment: Print Composer is difficult to work with but yes that is one solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterize` to add vector layers to a raster.

From the gdal_rasterize manpage:

> The following would burn all polygons from mask.shp into the RGB TIFF
>   file work.tif with the color red (RGB = 255,0,0).
>
> gdal_rasterize -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -l mask
>   mask.shp work.tif

---

You have to insert the -b and -burn options manually in QGIS. Make sure to have a RGB Raster for this.